# Create an independent web page inside another

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, browser

I'm facing a problem on my web project. I have a custom device based on a linux which run a QT QWebPage and work with a local Apache server to display a local web application.

Which I try is to display a external page (ie : www.google.com) inside my web application. The problem is that in my application I defined my window.location to localhost in order to run my personnal webapp. When I try to load the external page, it loads it partially because some files needed by the external page are in relative link (ie css/js file) and so my Apache server try to find them locally due to my window location.

If i change the window.location to the external page the display is ok but I haven't access to my webapp.

I **can't use window.open** to create the other page because the architecture of the device doesn't allow multipage.

My question is : **Is it possible to create an independent block in my HTML page with an other window.location than my parent page ?**

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Yes, using an iframe tag.

Comment: you already tagged iFrame so I suppose that you are aware of them. If you google a bit you will find plenty of examples on how to get your result!

Comment: Oh damn.... I've tried a lot to work with src attribute but never have the idea to make a frame.location.href.....

Sorry and thank you !